# undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x000000000d530ab8> even the instance variable has data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I am displaying the posts on a user profile. However, "undefined method `each' for #Post:0x000000000d530ab8" error keeps on showing up even I have the data and I checked the variable name on both controller and view.

users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @post = Post.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
end
```

users/show.html.rb

```
<div class="post-container">
  <% @post.each do |p| %>
    <div class="post">
      <h2><%= @user.username %></h2>
      <p><%= p.content %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

better-errors result

```
undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x000000000d530ab8>
```

I tried printing it by the code below, and it displays it.

```
<%= @post.inspect %>
```

Even the better-errors shows I have a **@post** instance variable, but I don't know why **each** doesn't work. I checked all the questions that I can see here related so please be nice.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `find_by_user_id` returns a single record not a collection. You cannot call `.each` on a single record. Perhaps change it to `Post.where(user_id: @user.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_by_user_id` method returns a single `Post` (or `nil` if it doesn't exist) and it does not respond to the `each` method. You want to fetch all the user's posts. If you have the `has_many :posts` association set up in the `User` model, you can do

```rb
@posts = @user.posts
```

You might also want to handle the case when `@user` is `nil`.

```rb
def show
  @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
  unless @user
    return redirect_to(root_path, alert: 'User not found')
  end
    
  @posts = @user.posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `@post.each` to do? `@post` is a single record, not a list of records.

Perhaps you meant:

```
@posts = Post.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

Or equivalently, assuming you've set up the model associations:

```
@posts = @user.posts
```